# Is there a MongoDB pattern for iterating chunks of similar data?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

We have a MongoDB containing customers and transactions. In a number of queries we want to pull all of the transactions for a customer into our application to do some processing. As far as I'm currently aware we have two options with different caveats:

1. Group by customer ID in an aggregation and `$push` the transactions into the group object. This can fail if the customers transactions sums >16MB
2. Return all transactions to the application and group by customer ID in memory before processing. This has the down-side of needing to pull a *lot* of data into memory.

Is there a pattern for solving this?

My idea would be to query *without* grouping so that our cursor would be a list of transactions, but somehow we retrieve chunks of transactions per customer ID. That way we would only ever have 1 customers transactions in memory and also not risk blowing up the document size in Mongo.

Comment: Pull all customer ids, then iterate their transactions, id by id. More chatty, yes, but, on the other hand, no need to download the entirety of transaction history upfront.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev, not a bad idea - we may be talking 3000+ customers at a time however so I would love if there was something a bit more efficient. I may give it a try though.

Comment: What do you mean, more efficient? Fetching 3k numbers from the database is nothing. You can even fetch them in batches, provided that customer ids grow monotonically (as they should, if they're ObjectIds)

Comment: 3k is quick - but iterating 3k times and making a query for >1,000 transactions each feels very chatty.

I may be imagining something that doesn't exist - but if the query has sorted our customer transactions by Customer ID:
Customer 1 - Transaction 1
Customer 1 - Transaction 2
Customer 2 - Transaction 1
Then I would love to have it iterate until the CustomerID changes and give me those transactions.

Comment: Honestly, that's not any different. A `find` with another customerID vs a `getMore()` against a cursor. It's still a query.

Comment: Of course, if you have many small customers (with only a few transactions per each), then the cursor may turn out faster. But fundamentally, it's the same approach.